# EventListner on entire fieldset element to monitor checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I need to monitor when checkboxes in a form have been checked or unchecked.
I have used getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0] with addEventLister. Inside the function, I have an if/else statement. It should console log if it has been checked but it goes to else every time and logs "unchecked" to the console. Should I be using this.checked or something else?

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/gOMVJzV?)

Here is the code

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0].addEventListener("change",function()
{

  if(this.checked) {
          // Checkbox is checked..
          console.log ("checked");
      } else {
          // Checkbox is not checked..
         console.log ("unchecked");
      }
  })
```

```html
  <fieldset><legend>Reporting Events</legend>
            <p>Select the events you want to listen for:</p>
            <div><label for="mouseover">mouseover</label><input type="checkbox" name="mouseover" id="mouseover" value="mouseover"></div>
            <div><label for="mouseout">mouseout</label><input type="checkbox" name="mouseout" id="mouseout" value="mouseout"></div>
            <div><label for="click">click</label><input type="checkbox" name="click" id="click" value="click"></div>
            <div><label for="keypress">keypress</label><input type="checkbox" name="keypress" id="keypress" value="keypress"></div>
            <div><label for="blur">blur</label><input type="checkbox" name="blur" id="blur" value="blur"></div>
            
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Just check what `this` is mate (console.log). `this.checked` will be always undefined in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were using `this` instead you should use event `e`.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0].addEventListener("change",function(e) {

if(e.target.checked) {
    // Checkbox is checked..
    console.log ("checked");
} else {
    // Checkbox is not checked..
    console.log ("unchecked");
}
});
```

```html
<fieldset><legend>Reporting Events</legend>
<p>Select the events you want to listen for:</p>
<div><label for="mouseover">mouseover</label><input type="checkbox" name="mouseover" id="mouseover" value="mouseover"></div>
<div><label for="mouseout">mouseout</label><input type="checkbox" name="mouseout" id="mouseout" value="mouseout"></div>
<div><label for="click">click</label><input type="checkbox" name="click" id="click" value="click"></div>
<div><label for="keypress">keypress</label><input type="checkbox" name="keypress" id="keypress" value="keypress"></div>
<div><label for="blur">blur</label><input type="checkbox" name="blur" id="blur" value="blur"></div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: That's it. I never understood what the e was for. Thank you!